# Set Organizational ID and record type for created entity

Tags: leads, .net, developer

I am using toolkit for .net to create leads, but I was asked to set two more things - Organizational Id and Lead Record Type when creating leads. Those two things don't have their own field, so how can I apply these two options while creating lead?

**Edit:**

It seems, that it is just that those fields are not generated. I managed to get RecordTypeId field after creating one, but how to get organization id field for Leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

See the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf) for a list of the standard fields available on Leads.

The RecordTypeId field appeared once you created the RecordType. You'll need to create a custom field to hold the Organization ID. The Org ID is fixed and can be found in the Organization object. There's no real need to create a look-up to it if you're working only within a single org. Otherwise, that's where you'd find it through a look-up, but again, you'd need a custom field to hold it. If I'm not mistaken, in a Web to Lead form, its added as a hidden field to help SF process the form.

You can find the Org's Id under Settings > Company Profile> Organization Detail, then look for Salesforce.com Organization ID at the bottom right of the top section of the Detail Page.

Comment: Sorry if I will mix up something and for many questions - So there is no field for organization in leads which could be created by default when activating some feature? So if I want to have organization id in my lead I have to add custom field or it already exists it just isn't showed through entity schema, if so what is that fields name?I have these questions because in web-to-lead functionality it seems organization id is quite important field, but I not using it so I want to put ends where it meets

Comment: See my revised answer. Org ID is found in the Organization object. You'll still need to create a custom field to hold it.